# How do I indicate that I am willing to pursue other options while still in education?

Tags: job-search, united-kingdom

I am currently taking time out from my teaching degree. The reason was, among other things, to consider whether it was really for me. Technically I am still a student, but until January I have no contact hours.

I'm applying for jobs at the moment. For temporary jobs, where this isn't a problem, I am completely open about this.

I am willing to consider dropping out if the right opportunity comes along, but how do I convey this to a hiring manager?

Comment: Aren't you implicitly saying this by applying for a job that would be incompatible with your studies? If you apply for a full time job I would ask you about your study plans and how you intended to organise them around the job during the interview.

Comment: @Dustybin80 If I get to the interview stage, that's fine. The problem is employers simply binning my application before then because my circumstances imply that I'd only be interested in short term work.

Comment: Well you could write on your resume your study dates InstitutionX 201X - 2015 this would give the indication that you have ended your studies. List any completed modules/courses and talk about your studies in the past tense in your covering letter. This should give the impression that you've finished and are looking for a permanent position.

Comment: Are you writing cover letters with your application or just sending in a resume? It's not clear from your question and cover letters aren't standard throughout the world (I've added a location tag based on your profile).

Comment: If they only send a resume they would either have to state in their personal statement they are looking to permanently move into employment and cease their studies, or implicitly suggest that in some manner like I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Have you given up on teaching?  You need to be honest with yourself and potential employers.  When January rolls around, what are you going to do if you don't love your new job, are you going back to school?  It's not fair to the employer to use them as an experiment.  You need to commit to something if you expect them to commit to you.

If you make misleading changes to your resume to get the interview and this comes up in discussion, that is just as likely to keep you from getting a job.  Trust is important, can they trust what you are telling them?  Can they trust that you are serious about making this job work?

Sometimes it is amazing how small the work world is.  You could very easily run into any of these contacts again in the future.  You don't want to damage your reputation while trying to sort out what you really want to work on.  Be up front with the information and believe that in the long run things will work out.